# Unwanted files in Downloads directory from a failed OS upgrade attempt

Tags: 14.04, uninstall, files

Downloaded ubuntu 15.04 and in the middle of setting it up decided to keep 14.04. That left files such as boot, install, and WUBI.exe in the Download directory. Neither 14.04 nor the Terminal, using the rm command, would erase them. What next?

Comment: did you try `sudo rm`?

Comment: What about launching Nautilus using `gksu nautilus`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type the following commands:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo rm -rf wubi.exe install boot
```

(or whatever the file names are of the files still remaining)

### Done! ;)

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**